# how do I restart nginx which is install by passenger

Tags: nginx, passenger

I installed nginx by `passenger-install-nginx-module` , and start nginx by `/opt/nginx/sbin/nginx`, but I don't know how to stop or restart nginx after I update my nginx conf.

I know I can use the way `ps aux | grep` and `kill`, it there a way like `services restart nginx` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nginx` is build to reload configuration without the need for a restart.  The common way to restart `nginx` is to first do

```
nginx -t
```

Which will analyse the configuration file and tell you if there are any problems (this is very convenient since syntax errors in the configuration file means downtime).  And then

```
nginx -s reload
```

Will reload the configuration and restart `nginx` workers one by one with the new config.  This simply finds the master `nginx` process and sends it the right signal (this is not much different from your `ps axu | grep` and `kill`, it just uses a different signal).

[There are several other useful command line options for configuration and logging](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/).  Being aware of them lets you run `nginx` practically without any downtime.